# Date text box should be always 1st date current month.?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I want a javascript or java program should always give date 1st of current month.
Is there any tech?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Calendar for **Java**

```
      Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
      cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTime(date);
      cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Now you do what every you want to do with this Calendar object like to get the Day of the Week (Sat, Sun, .... )

```
int weekday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

---

And for **JavaScript** you can use:

```
var theFirst = new Date();
theFirst.setDate(1);
```

`setDate` sets the day of the month for the Date object *(from 1 to 31)*.  Then you can do whatever you want with theFirst, like get the day of the week.

Comment: Thanx Khan... both ur Ex is very useful for beginners like me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar ans = Calendar.getInstance();

ans.set(ans.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        ans.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0
);
System.out.println(ans.getTime());
```